# Why ORDER BY on integer column is not working as expected

Tags: mysql

I have a table schema like below

```
CREATE TABLE test( qid varchar(255), qor int );
```

And I am trying to retrieve QID order by qor like below

```
SELECT DISTINCT qid from test ORDER BY qor + 0;
```

But it is not working as I expect it to sort qor first and then retrieve distinct qid values from selection. please have a look into [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0beb7/3/0)

Comment: How isn't it working?  The fiddle you linked seems to match your stated expectations.

Comment: Can you provide the expect output ? The output seem fine to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I expect it to sort qor first and then retrieve distinct qid values

That's not how it works. Distinct values are handled first, order is handled later. Otherwise, imagine this data:

```
qid    qor
'foo'    0
'bar'    1
'foo'    2
```

If it sorted by `qor` first (already done here), what would the order of the resulting records be? Is `foo` before `bar`, or after?    "*Yes*."        As you can see here and in the comments to another answer, the first three people to respond each interpreted it in a different way: one SUM, one MAX, and one MIN. That's no good.

If MySql followed ansi rules, what you have wouldn't even be legal sql, because after grouping by `qid` (which is what a `distinct` operator does) there is no way to know which `qor` value was used for the result. ANSI SQL requires any columns used after an aggregate operation (like distinct) be part of the aggregation, for reasons like the one I just demonstrated.

What you can do is something like this:

```
SELECT qid 
FROM test 
GROUP BY qid
ORDER BY MIN(qor);
```

Of course, MAX, AVG, etc would also work instead of MIN, depending on how you wanted to handle that situation.

Answer (score 2):

You want to group by the `qid`. You need an aggregate function on the `qor` column. I assume you want to sum up all `qor` for the `qid`s

```
SELECT qid, sum(qor) as total_qor
from test 
group by qid
ORDER BY total_qor desc;
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0beb7/9)

An alternative would be to sort by the highest `qor`. Then use `max()` instead of `sum()`

Comment: I was about to answer using a max() alternative.

Comment: I had the sense he expected it to roll UP, and so provided an answer suggesting MIN. I almost didn't post when I saw yours, but I thought I had enough additional explanation to justify it.